# Trying to read values only once among several times

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have retrieve value from database which has 19 repeated columns values
and wanted if once value is read then not need to repeat 19 times for same condition 
and then control should goes to next condition match.
Actually i want to print the page as pdf but currently in pdf it is printing 19 times same 
value .Any idea how to restrict it to one time.

```
OracleDataReader ReadData = objFetchCmd.ExecuteReader();
 while (ReadData.Read())
  {
   if (p_name == "1snp")
   {  
    lblND_Tr.InnerText = lblND_Tr.InnerText + t_property +"," ;                            
    }
   if (p_name == "1pns")
   {
     lblPD_Tr.InnerText = lblPD_Tr.InnerText + t_property +"," ;                            
    }
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: if you are taking data from database why can't you use distinct ?and what is lblND_Tr ?

Comment: This should be solved on query level. Just select only 1 row

Comment: use distinct to avoid repeated data  as you are retrieving from db

Answer (score 1):

The problem does not rely in your code just modify your `SQL query` with `Distinct`.
like select distinct  from ;
EX: `Select distinct * from student;`

```
objFetchCmd.CommandText="select distinct * from student";
OracleDataReader ReadData = objFetchCmd.ExecuteReader();
```